# PostgreSQL 9.3 How to get alias in output when using json_agg

Tags: postgresql, output, alias

Is it possible to get PostgreSQL to not just output the data I requested, but also the alias(es) I used.

Example:

```
 SELECT json_agg(a) as Alias_a,
   json_agg(b) as Alias_b,
   json_agg(c) as Alias_c,
    ...
   json_agg(z)as Alias_z
 FROM table_a a
   LEFT JOIN table_b b using(b_id)
   LEFT JOIN table_c c using(c_id)
   ...
   LEFT JOIN table_z z using(z_id)
 ;
```

output:

```
[{"a_id":1,"b_id":2,"c_id":3},
 {"a_id":2,"b_id":51,"c_id":3}]
[{"b_id":2,"name":"John Doe", "z_id":123},
 {"b_id":51,"name":"Mary Ann", "z_id":412}]
[{"c_id":3, "OS type":"Windows 7"}]
[{"z_id":123, "Whatever":"Something"},
{"z_id":123, "Whatever":"Something else"}]
```

How would I achieve an output including the alias like this instead:

output:

```
"Alias_a":[{"a_id":1,"b_id":2,"c_id":3},
 {"a_id":2,"b_id":51,"c_id":3}]
"Alias_b":[{"b_id":2,"name":"John Doe", "z_id":123},
 {"b_id":51,"name":"Mary Ann", "z_id":412}]
"Alias_c":[{"c_id":3, "OS type":"Windows 7"}]
"Alias_z":[{"z_id":123, "Whatever":"Something"},
{"z_id":123, "Whatever":"Something else"}]
```

Edit:
This is Igor's solution, how it worked for me:

```
SELECT row_to_json(t) 
FROM ( SELECT json_agg(a) as Alias_a, ... -- your current query here
) t;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
SELECT row_to_json(*) 
FROM ( SELECT json_agg(a) as Alias_a, ... -- your current query here
) sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It wouldn't allow me to use the asterisk. But replacing this and the word sub with some letter (I used t) worked.